# ошибка при запуске opencv python

Tags: python, opencv

Доброго времени суток. Не могу понять, в чём ошибка. Запускал в первый раз - всё запустилось, второй раз - уже нет. В чём может быть ошибка? P.S Скажу сразу, в этом я недавно, ранее лишь на Java сидел. Ошибка может быть элементарной)

Код:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from PIL import ImageGrab

kernelOpen=np.ones((5,5))
kernelClose=np.ones((20,20))


while(True):
    #Get current window
    frames = np.array(ImageGrab.grab(bbox =(0,40,1280,720)))
    #Convert window to RGB format
    framess = cv2.cvtColor(frames, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    frame = cv2.GaussianBlur(framess, (17, 17), 0) 
    #Convert window to HSV format
    hsvs = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    hsv= cv2.GaussianBlur(hsvs, (17, 17), 0)

    lower_red = np.array([20, 100, 100])
    upper_red = np.array([30, 255, 255])

    mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_red, upper_red)
    maskOpen=cv2.morphologyEx(mask,cv2.MORPH_OPEN,kernelOpen)
    maskClose=cv2.morphologyEx(maskOpen,cv2.MORPH_CLOSE,kernelClose)
    maskFinal=maskClose
    im, conts, h = cv2.findContours(maskFinal.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
    center =None
    c=max(conts, key=cv2.contourArea)
    ((x, y), radius) = cv2.minEnclosingCircle(c)
    M = cv2.moments(c)
    center = (int(M["m10"] / M["m00"]), int(M["m01"] / M["m00"]))
    cv2.putText(frame,"Distance", (center[0]+10,center[1]), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.4,(0, 0, 255),1)
    cv2.putText(frame,"("+str(center[0])+","+str(center[1])+")", (center[0]+10,center[1]+15), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.4,(0, 0, 255),1)
    cv2.drawContours(hsv,conts,-1,(255,0,0),3)
    for i in range(len(conts)):
        x,y,w,h=cv2.boundingRect(conts[i])
        cv2.rectangle(frame,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,0,255), 2)
    res = cv2.bitwise_and(frame,frame, mask= mask)

    cv2.imshow('original', frame)


    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Andrey\Desktop\test123.py", line 28, in <module>
    c = max(conts, key=cv2.contourArea)
ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence
```

Comment: Может ошибку кинешь?

Comment: Да... Забыл. Добавил ошибку

Comment: Все логично, conts пустой. Значит контур не найден. Скорее всего так.

Comment: Для создание крупный приложений используйте отладчики. Так проще, хоть это и лёгкий и хорошо читаемый язык.

Comment: @MrBin, btw судя по тексту ошибки даже отладчик не нужен, всё напеисано и где и почему :)

Comment: @AntonKomyshan, я и написал выше. Но лучше использовать отладчик, если не шаришь в языке и непривычно работать из командной строки.

Answer (score 2):

Раз написано `is an empty sequence`, значит `conts` пустой:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Andrey\Desktop\test123.py", line 28, in <module>
    c = max(conts, key=cv2.contourArea)
ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence
```

Думаю, `print(conts)` выдаст `[]`

Чтобы ошибки не было нужно добавить проверку, например:

```
while True:
    ...

    im, conts, h = cv2.findContours(maskFinal.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
    if not conts:
        print('Not found contours')
        continue
    ...
```